# Adding a Procedural Crater to a Terrain Created by ANT Landscapes

Tags: error, procedural

I created a terrain with ANT landscape that looks like this:
[image]

I looked up a tutorial on how to create a crater and followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7OpmpE8xTc) from CGMatter.

I created a crater that looked like this:
[image]

Nodes looked like this:
[image]

But when i tried to apply this material to the terrain created by ANT Landscapes it looked like this:
[image]

Is there a way I can make this work or another way I can have a crater in this terrain?

Answer (score 5):

That can be this kind of settings.

[image]

What is happening in the nodes shown in the question is *"displacement"* node is going along the faces normals, and they should go down.

(this issue does not occur in the video tutorial as he uses a flat plane)

So I've used a *"vector displacement"* that allows to displace along the wanted vector (0, 0, 1).

(the other parts of the node tree is on the same base as yours)

[image]